# convert generic type to listbox control

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm using silverlight framework 4: I'm trying to list my items in a generic list to a listbox control: But the only data a receive is the classname itself.

lsBox => the listbox control
lsTags => generic type

My question is: how can I add my items in the generic list, to the listbox control?

my code is:

```
 lsBox.ItemsSource = lsTags;
```

Comment: +1 to reverse harsh -1.  People give the newbies a chance please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties of your `ListBox` control to tell ListBox which property's value should be displayed for every item and which property should be used for determening `ListBox.SelectedValue` property. Or use `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to display a complex data like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="usersInGroupLBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding User.UserName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Do not forget, you can use only **public properties** for binding. Check you class `Tag`.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `ListBox` (and most other controls) for displaying user types is to call the `ToString()` method. The default behavior of that is to display the class name.

What you should do depends on what you want to display, but if it's something simple like displaying the value of the `Name` property, just set the [`DisplayMemberPath` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=VS.95%29.aspx):

```
<ListBox Name="lsBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: But, i'm reading the values of a .xml file: the generic variable lsTags contains the data and I will just bind the data to a ListBox?

Comment: Yeah, bind the data directly to the listbox. The exact way to display the data depends on what type `IsTags` is and what do you want to display.

Comment: Yeas.. I try to do that. But the result is: Clipboard.Tag (name of my project) Tag name of other class for .xml file. The lsTags is type List<Tag>.